# Windows Server Administration - which services are safe to run internet facing?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, security, sql-server, windows-server-2012

Coming from a Linux background and now having to manage some Windows servers (2008R2 & 2012R2) I'm wondering which services are safe to run directly over the internet. The servers are all internet facing without additional hardware firewall or a internal VPN management network.

The services in doubt are:

1. RDP (in standard configuration)?
2. MSSQL (2012)?
3. Active Directory?
4. WSUS (without domain if 3. is unsafe)?

After some research I know that RDP atleast was unsafe in earlier Windows versions (2003) and AD seems generally to be considered unsafe. Is it still a wise idea to tunnel RDP over SSH (the servers all run cygwin)?

Thank's for your advice!

Comment: are we talking having internet *access* or have the service server *serve over the internet*

Comment: @BigHomie The servers are all "standalone servers" with no safe internal network - so the latter one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My opinion in these cases is to port block every single port except those that are required for the server to perform it's primary purpose (http/s, ftp, sql server), and even then, restrict those ports to only certain IP blocks when possible. Don't configure any remote connectivity for these servers except for those necessary services.

Then deploy a [bastion host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host). This is an extremely hardened host which does have remote connectivity enabled (ssh, rdp, vpn), and will allow you to double-hop to your other hosts. I know a lot of people consider this unnecessary and overkill, but honestly, it's the safest way to roll.

Comment: This is the proper answer in my opinion - there is no magic "this is a safe thing to run end of discussion" list - don't expose services unless you need to, don't leave those services unmanaged/unpatched, etc. Simple as - what operating system you're running and stuff like that doesn't even enter into the debate here.

Comment: That really sound's like a great idea for RDP. Thank's for that. Regarding AD and WSUS, would you consider it safe to run those services on the bastion host as long as the communication on this ports is limited to static IP's on both client & server?

Comment: AD is really intended for internal networks, so no, I wouldn't put it internet-facing unless you have a pressing business need to do so.  And I'd still use VPN for RDP.

Answer (score -1):

RPD should be used only via VPN.

SQL can connect with a specific port, so it should be safe.

Why would one run AD on internet side ? If you have to run it on the same server connected to the internet, you should thoroughly check the security policies before doing so.

WSUS is bugged and unsafe. WSUS can even report that everything is current while having long-time-ago-created patches not applied. It makes the system vulnerable and can affect security policies.
Better save some downtime for patching when necessary and let WSUS disabled.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Are you sure that the current versions of RDP are unsafe? I'm curious, because when you buy a dedicated Windows server from any provider, they come preinstalled with RDP enabled - why would they all do this if RDP was really unsafe these days?

Comment: PS To answer your question: I asked about WSUS and AD solely for management purposes, i.e. making management of these servers easier.

Comment: It is not RDP itself but the way you use it. To make it safe, use it via VPN (encryption, SSH or others) --edit-- Then use RDP via VPN to connect to any machine in the network and you can handle the rest form there. No everything has to be on the machine you connect to, even if it seem easier.

Comment: RDP ONLY via vp no, -1. THat is also nice with Terminal Services Gateway - no need to force a vpn here ;)

Comment: @TomTom +1, it only adds unneeded complexity in most cases, and worst case the user would eat up a VPN license and porcessing power of the VPN. In addition to TS Gateway, you could also do RDPWeb as well.

Comment: You don't need to pay anything; there are plenty of free solutions. Additionally, if you have some good networking equipment, you can set it up from that one. TS is too vulnerable.